# Download a zip file from one folder location to another

Tags: c#, zip

```
using Ionic.Zip;

var savedzipFile = "C:\alldocs\issues\issuesfromtoday.zip";
var selectedfolderfromDialog = "D:\MyDocs";
```

This is what I have. I cant use webblient because its not a url. How to I save the zip file to that selected folder location? Zip file has PDFs if that matters.

Comment: Why not just use `File.Copy(savedzipFile, Path.Combine(selectedfolderfromDialog, "issuesfromtoday.zip" ));`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var savedzipFile = @"C:\alldocs\issues\issuesfromtoday.zip";
var selectedfolderfromDialog = @"D:\MyDocs";
using (var sourceStream = System.IO.File.Open(savedzipFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{ 
    using (var targetStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(selectedfolderfromDialog + @"\" + savedzipFile.Substring(savedzipFile.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
    { 
        sourceStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
    }
}
```